# Facebook Api Bulk message as Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'd like to use the endpoint ['{conversation-id}/messages'](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/conversation/messages) to send bulk messages. According to the [latest update on policies](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/08/15/updated-messenger-platform-policies/) i can send 1 message to each user (says nothing about the users count) outside the 24 hours window ( when i can send multiple messages ).

Can anyone confirm to me that "The restriction on promotional content has been removed for **standard messaging**." includes the Api endpoint i stated above? is it standard as in non-'bot-like'? or standard as in using the web app ?

Also, if i break the policies in this regard, do they ban the app, the developer or the page?:D

Comment: It is still just for bots.

Comment: “Standard” as in Standard Messaging, regarding Messenger Platform. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy-overview The Send API in question is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference

Comment: How you send bulk message from page? I need your help brother.